# resource linking failed in AndroidManifest.xml when using sourceSets

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I am trying to run an Android Studio project, but I keep getting 'Android resource linking failed' error for values in the AndroidManifest.xml.

Resource linking error

[image]

When I remove the sourceSets from the build.gradle it solves this problem but breaks imports of the files referenced in the sourceSets.

The sourceSets in build.gradle look like this:

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        res.srcDirs =
                [
                        '/src/main/res/layouts/administrator',
                        '/src/main/res/layouts/dashboard',
                        '/src/main/res/layouts/location_information',
                        '/src/main/res/layouts/login',
                        '/src/main/res/layouts/map',
                        '/src/main/res/layouts/non_activity',
                        '/src/main/res/layouts/register_location',
                        '/src/main/res/layouts/start_up',
                        '/src/main/res/layouts',
                        '/src/main/res'
                ]
    }
}
```

The Android Manifest looks like this:

AndroidManifest cannot resolve @string

[image]

Is there some other way I should be accessing the values in the AndroidManifest other than @string... ?

I have tried various build tools versions and disabling AAPT2. Any help on resolving these linking issues would be appreciated.

Top of build.gradle:

```
compileSdkVersion 28
buildToolsVersion "28.0.3"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.example"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 4
    versionName "1.3.1"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
}
```

Comment: Why are you walking all the paths in your layouts? I have no idea why you would ever need to do that. Please provide clarity as to what you are trying to accomplish and why you are walking the res paths. As you don't set res paths unless you are using an outdated structure or a hybrid tool that is using an outdated structure.

Comment: This is a project I have taken over, I am not sure why it is laid out like this. I am just wondering how the resources should be accessed in the AndoidManifest if this is the set up? Would I be better off restructuring?

Comment: I would, yeah. You should use the natural folder structure or you will be fighting little one-off errors like this when it comes down to testing and unit testing and flavors later. The natural structure of a new android project is very easy to follow. Just create a new project to see how it should be laid out. Then start moving yours to match it. Once they match delete the res-dir snippet from your gradle. That will probably clear you up.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late ... but simply removing `/` before `src` should redirect you to the proper directory.